# numpy.genfromtxt cannot read boolean data correctly

Tags: numpy

No matter what the input value is, the [`np.genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) will always return `False`.

Using `dtype='u1'` I get '1' as expected. But with `dtype='b1'` (Numpy's bool) I get 'False'.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, using NumPY 1.9.0. Could you add an explicit example?

Comment: 1.8.x and 1.6.x has this problem. In new version this probably has been fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if this is a bug or not, but so far, I've been able to get `dtype=bool` to work (without an explicit converter) only if the file contains the literal strings 'False' and 'True':

```
In [21]: bool_lines = ['False,False', 'False,True', 'True,False', 'True,True']

In [22]: genfromtxt(bool_lines, delimiter=',', dtype=bool)
Out[22]: 
array([[False, False],
       [False,  True],
       [ True, False],
       [ True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

If your data is 0s and 1s, you can read it as integers and then convert to bool:

```
In [26]: bits = ['0,0', '0,1', '1,0', '1,1']

In [27]: genfromtxt(bits, delimiter=',', dtype=np.uint8).astype(bool)
Out[27]: 
array([[False, False],
       [False,  True],
       [ True, False],
       [ True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Or you can use a converter for each column

```
In [28]: cnv = lambda s: bool(int(s))

In [29]: converters = {0: cnv, 1: cnv}

In [30]: genfromtxt(bits, delimiter=',', dtype=bool, converters=converters)
Out[30]: 
array([[False, False],
       [False,  True],
       [ True, False],
       [ True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: `genfromtxt` is using `np.lib._iotools.StringConverter(bool)` to convert strings to bool.  It handles upper/lower case 'True/False', and returns error for anything else.